# How to get the name and maximum sum values of points for each year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

This is my code so far. It's in T-SQL.

However, it only selects the item with max values for each year instead of the total points.

```sql
WITH cte as
(
   SELECT
     CONCAT(forename,' ',surname) AS driver_name,
     year,
     (CONVERT(FLOAT,points)) AS race_points,
     row_number() over (partition by year order by (CONVERT(FLOAT,points)) desc) as rn     
   FROM 
     results AS r    
     INNER JOIN constructors AS c ON r.constructorId = c.constructorId
     INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON r.driverId = d.driverId
     INNER JOIN races AS rc ON r.raceId = rc.raceId
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1
```

This is how **sub** looks like

| driver_name | year | race_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2011 | 1 |
| a | 2011 | 1 |
| b | 2011 | 2 |
| b | 2011 | 2 |
| c | 2012 | 3 |
| c | 2012 | 3 |
| d | 2012 | 4 |
| d | 2012 | 4 |

I'm trying to make it look like this

| driver_name | year | max_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2011 | 4 |
| d | 2012 | 8 |

What I'm currently getting is this

| driver_name | year | max_points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 2011 | 2 |
| d | 2012 | 4 |

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You aren't aggregating your values in the CTE; add the aggregation and you have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want aggregation with the window functions:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname) AS driver_name,
             year, SUM(points) as race_points,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM results r JOIN 
           constructors c
           ON r.constructorId = c.constructorId JOIN
           drivers d
           ON r.driverId = d.driverId JOIN
           races rc
           ON r.raceId = rc.raceId
      GROUP BY CONCAT(forename, ' ', surname), year
     )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```